# infinitely isomorphism classes of $k[X]$-modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, finite-groups, modules

I need to prove the follow:
let $k$ be a field and $k[X]$ your polynomial ring. Given $n \in \mathbb{N}$ then there are infinitely isomorphism classes of $k[X]$-modules of dimension $n$

My idea:
If $M$ is a $k[X]$-module  there exists $\rho_M: k[X] \to \operatorname{End}_k(M)$, besides.
I know that if $M$ and $N$ are $k[X]$-modules finitely generated, then they are isomorphic if and only if $\rho_M$ and $\rho_N$ are conjugates.

Now, we suppose that there is $M_1,...,M_T$ elements in the class of $k[X]$-modules of dimension $n$, I want to find other $k[X]$-module isomorphic to these.

I believe that this modulo is for example $\operatorname{Im} p^i_1 \oplus \operatorname{Im} p^i_2$ where $i$ is any in $1,...,t$ and $p^i_1, p^i_2 \in \operatorname{End}_k(M_i)$ such that $ p^i_1 \circ p^i_2 = p^i_2 \circ p^i_1 = 0$, $(p^i_j)^2 = p^i_j $ and $p^i_1 + p^i_2 = \operatorname{Id}_{M_i}$.

my problem is that I don't know if the fact that $M_i$ is finitely generated of dimension $n$ allows me to conclude or prove in some way that these $p^i_1, p^i_2 \in End_k(M_i)$ exist.

If I go down a bad path, could you give me any recommendations? to prove it

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by dimension for a $k[X]$-module $V$ ? Is it the rank of the module, that is the dimension of $V \otimes_{k[X]} k(X)$ as a $k(X)$-vector space ?

Comment: My definition is: A finitely generated $A$-module $M$ is a module of the form $<X>$ for $X$ a finite subset of $M$.

Comment: You didn't answer my question. You wrote you want to prove there exist infinitely many isomorphism classes of $k[X]$-module of **dimension $n$**. But even if your $k[X]$-module is finitely generated, it is not necessary a $Z[X]$-free module. Thus the notion of dimension is not defined for such modules.

Comment: @Halbaroth A $k[X]$-module is also a $k$-vector space, and I would guess that by dimension the OP means dimension as a $k$-vector space.

Comment: @ahren.baz Do you know that $k[X]$-modules $M$ are in bijection with $k$-vector spaces $V$ equipped with a $k$-linear endomorphism $T: V \to V$? (The endomorphism $T$ is simply $\rho_M(X)$.) So it suffices to show that there are infinitely many conjugacy classes of endomorphisms $V \to V$. However, unless I'm missing something, the statement looks false when $k$ is a finite field.

Comment: It is exactly why I asked him what he meant by dimension. If you replace dimension by rank, the statement holds for any field since it's sufficient to prove there are infinitely many irreducible elements in $k[X]$ pairwise relatively prime.